# GPU: the fastest way to transpose, reshape and multiply two matrices

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, gpu, linear-algebra

What is the fastest way to transpose, reshape and multiply two matrices in Matlab? I want to do the following:

```
B = B';
B = reshape(B, 20, 5 000 000);
A = A * B
```

where A is 20 x 20 real matrix and B is 25 million x 4 real matrix. Using the implementation above, the transpose operation is ~4 times slower than the matrix multiplication (on GPU).

I heard about [dgemm](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d2b/dgemm_8f.html) which seems relevant, but not exactly what I'm looking for (it allows one to multiply matrices, transpose them and add stride (see LDA argument) in a single and fast operation).

I'm mostly interested in the case when both A and B are already gpuArrays and we are using modern nVidia GPU hardware.

Comment: Just in case, try `.'` to transpose instead of `'`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't know about this .' vs ' thing. However, in this case, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: If the data has no complex part (i.e. `isreal` returns true), there is no difference between those two. But it is a useful distinction to be aware of.

Comment: Hm, I can't see any way to speed this up much. What GPU are you using? Here on my K20c / WIN64 / R2014b, and using `gputimeit`, I see 0.02s for the transpose/reshape, and 0.045s for the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Before I ran only on my laptop with nVidia GeForce 740M. Now I tried the same code on the Amazon EC2 instance (g2.2xlarge) and get results similar to yours -- the bottleneck is the matrix multiplication. I'm afraid you're right and there is nothing to do here :(
Thanks anyway!